# How to have error message on ajax modal and not close and open in the full view

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an Ajax popup that opens a page when a link is selected like this.`@Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Change your password", "ChangePassword", null, "btn btn-info btn-sm")`

When I get an error from form not correct it closes the modal and takes me to the full page with the error. My question is, how do I keep it from closing and going to the full page and have the error show up on the modal form?

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { tabName = "settings", Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View(model);
    }
```

I need it to "return" to the popup or just show the error there rather than closing and reopening the full page. The page can be viewed, by the way, in either full or popup. Via the code below on the page.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
if (Ajax.IsThisAjaxRequest())
{
    Layout = null;
}
else
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated and if you need to see my modal dialog extensions just ask..

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The below code is used all over in my project. I tried to use it earlier and did not have much success with a "Success" return. Because it doesn't have the ability to get the Id of the record, since this uses `IdentyModel` and a lot of the code is actually in metadata. However to return a false it works just fine. So I had to reconfigure the code so I could get it to work properly. Since a big part of how this works is written in classes the method will not make sense to some. But if you are someone who has been coding a while you should have no problem piecing it together. I will try to explain in the simplest terms.

I have a class that is called ModalDialogExtentions. In this class I have several different variations of uses. Uses for just a link, link with css, links with objects `id = @model.Id`. This is used to open a dialog window of the page without a layout. below is an example.
This is the link that opens the page:
 `@Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Change your password", "ChangePassword", null, "btn btn-info btn-sm")`

```
    sealed class DialogActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        public DialogActionResult(string message)
        {
            Message = message ?? string.Empty;
        }

        string Message { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<script>   window.location.assign('" + Message + "')   </script>");
        }
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString ModalDialogActionLink(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string ControllerName, string dialogTitle, string CssClass, object routeValues)
    {
        var dialogDivId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, ControllerName, routeValues,
                ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = dialogDivId,
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    OnBegin = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "prepareModalDialog('{0}')", dialogDivId),
                    OnFailure = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "clearModalDialog('{0}');alert('You are not authorized to access this area!')", dialogDivId),
                    OnSuccess = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "openModalDialog('{0}', '{1}')", dialogDivId, dialogTitle)
                }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = CssClass });
    }

    public static bool IsThisAjaxRequest(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper)
    {
        bool result = false;
        var currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        if (currentContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != null
            && currentContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }



    public static ActionResult DialogResult(this Controller controller)
    {
        return DialogResult(controller, string.Empty);
    }

    public static ActionResult DialogResult(this Controller controller, string message)
    {
        return new DialogActionResult(message);
    }
```

I only added the one MvcHtmlString here, for sake of not posting the whole class. But you can add others that do not have all the value in it. Because if a link does not have an object it will not work unless you add another one that does not have that. When you try to put the link in it will be underlined squiggly red line because you do not have an object that is required. just copy / paste in the class right under it and remove the object for `routeValues` and any instance of it.

The page requires a bit of code also:
`@Html.StarkAjaxFormSubmiter("frmChangePassword", "tbAspNetUsers", true, "Action Successfully Executed")`

then in the form we have this:
`@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmChangePassword" }))`

The id is used to return the success or error. In this particular case we will only be returning the error. And the success will be handled by a return to index with a message. On this page I have a tabbed layout so I return, if successful, to the page and tab that I was in.

Here is the controller code that I needed help with in the question. On other instances I usually check model state after the try, but here I already had an `if(result.Succeeded) so I just used that instead and if it doesn't return Succeeded it will go to the else where I grab the` AddErrors(result)`so`sb.Append` can populate the errors.

New Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        try
        {

            var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                }
                    // not need as the sb.string is working correctly! 
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { tabName = "settings", Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    sb.Append("Sumitted");
                    return Content(sb.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
                foreach (var key in this.ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
                {
                    foreach (var err in this.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
                    {
                        sb.Append(err.ErrorMessage + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }          
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
        }

        return Content(sb.ToString());
    }
```

And if it does return "Success" then on the page some JavaScript to open the right tab.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabName = (window.location.href.match(/[?&]tab-name=[^&$]+/i) || '=').split('=')[1];

    if (tabName.length)
        $('#myTabs .nav-link[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Lastly on the ModalDialogExtensions here are the usings

Hope this was not to long but I did not want to post just the new code, because I didn't think it would make sense to most who were looking at it. There is also a .dll file that was custom made for this, I did not write it, but I have taken what it gave me and expanded its use. Anyone reading this interested just let me know and we will figure out a way to get you the .dll file.

UPDATE:
I ended up getting the success to work as it should so I removed the redirect to Index with open correct tab, Since this works properly there is no refresh and it stays on the correct tab on "Success".